# Navigation Drawer gets stuck in few fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

Here, I want to know how I can make smooth navigation drawer while switching fragments. I'm using a custom navigation drawer using Toolbar and whenever I switch few fragments it gets stuck in few fragments which has Map etc. but it smoothly works where I have only a text view. Can anyone please help me to resolve it?

```
/**
 * Diplaying fragment view for selected nav drawer list item
 */

public int displayView(int position, int position2, int position3) {
    // update the main content by replacing fragments
    Fragment fragment = null;
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("sharePref", 0);
            cb = sharedPreferences.getBoolean("ConfirmLogin", false);
            if (cb) {
            } else
                fragment = new LoginActivity();
            break;
        case 3:
            fragment = new MainTabFragment();
            break;
        case 4:
            fragment = new ContactUs();
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    if (fragment != null) {
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        final Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putInt("pos_next", position2);
        bundle.putInt("pos_end", position3);
        fragment.setArguments(bundle);
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(com.cws.advisorymandi.R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();
        // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
        mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
        mDrawerList.setSelection(position);
        // setTitle(navMenuTitles[position]);
    } else {
        // error in creating fragment
        Log.e("MainActivity", "Error in creating fragment");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: We can't do anything without seeing some of your code.

Comment: You need to add code

Comment: @AjitPratapSingh check

Answer (score 0):

The scrolling of the map view is interfering with scrolling of the pager.I think you need to control scrolling by using
       http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#canScroll(android.view.View, boolean, int, int, int)

This will inform the pager when it can scroll and when it cannot

Comment: There is no issue of scrolling on map.

Comment: What I meant was that there could be problems when you have a scrollable child within a pager

Comment: I do. I have more than 10 fragments in a fragment